# Docker windows container and "npm is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: docker

I'm trying to configure a dockerfile for a .NET and React deployment (for testing anyways).

For testing (since I couldn't get my own to work), I copied the code from here: https://github.com/StefanScherer/dockerfiles-windows/blob/main/node/12/nano/Dockerfile

That all runs fine.

I added my specific stuff at the bottom of that existing code which looks like:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /src
COPY . /src
RUN dotnet restore "MyProject.csproj"

#2 Build client-side artifacts
WORKDIR /node
COPY ./ClientApp /node
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
```

The problem is the last two lines. It errors with `'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

The last couple lines of the code from the github file includes:

```
ARG SETX=/M
USER ContainerAdministrator
RUN setx %SETX% PATH "%PATH%;C:\nodejs;C:\yarn\bin;C:\git\cmd;C:\git\mingw64\bin;C:\git\usr\bin"
USER ContainerUser

CMD [ "node.exe" ]
```

So I'm not sure why my npm command doesn't work.

Comment: Is `npm` installed in the container and is it in the path before you are trying to call it? Try moving the `npm` commands under `setx` line since this line is adding the node environment to the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For multi-stage build, the binary installed in former stage won't be automatically installed in next stage, so for `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env`, it won't have `npm` installed.

A workable solution could be next, FYI.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS downloadnodejs
RUN mkdir -p C:\\nodejsfolder
WORKDIR C:\\nodejsfolder
SHELL ["pwsh", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';$ProgressPreference='silentlyContinue';"]
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile nodejs.zip -UseBasicParsing "https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.16.3/node-v10.16.3-win-x64.zip"; Expand-Archive nodejs.zip -DestinationPath C:\\; Rename-Item "C:\\node-v10.16.3-win-x64" C:\\nodejs

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
COPY --from=downloadnodejs C:\\nodejs C:\\Windows\\system32
RUN npm --version
```

The first stage download nodejs, while second stage copy the installed binary to `C:\\Windows\\system32`, so now you could find `npm`, the output for your reference:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  15.36kB
Step 1/8 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS downloadnodejs
 ---> ef0fd0a1b52b
Step 2/8 : RUN mkdir -p C:\\nodejsfolder
 ---> Running in aa25433e2764
Removing intermediate container aa25433e2764
 ---> 2df344def0c2
Step 3/8 : WORKDIR C:\\nodejsfolder
 ---> Running in ad3763476e9c
Removing intermediate container ad3763476e9c
 ---> bc6e51239bcd
Step 4/8 : SHELL ["pwsh", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';$ProgressPreference='silentlyContinue';"]
 ---> Running in 7b63a6a32fed
Removing intermediate container 7b63a6a32fed
 ---> 045fb2ddce26
Step 5/8 : RUN Invoke-WebRequest -OutFile nodejs.zip -UseBasicParsing "https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.16.3/node-v10.16.3-win-x64.zip"; Expand-Archive nodejs.zip -DestinationPath C:\\; Rename-Item "C:\\node-v10.16.3-win-x64" C:\\nodejs
 ---> Running in 4bae736669e9
Removing intermediate container 4bae736669e9
 ---> 2e7619fcc452
Step 6/8 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env
 ---> ef0fd0a1b52b
Step 7/8 : COPY --from=downloadnodejs C:\\nodejs C:\\Windows\\system32
 ---> 1bb13ffbbffe
Step 8/8 : RUN npm --version
 ---> Running in a3c6a87a24b6
6.9.0
Removing intermediate container a3c6a87a24b6
 ---> 6c4ad12186e8
Successfully built 6c4ad12186e8
Successfully tagged abc:1
```